# Old Stack Overflow icon is still using in the Twitter tweet's GIF

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, twitter

As part of the #StackOverflowKnows there is a tweet about Security SE from the Stack Overflow Twitter account, in that there is a GIF file added. But the GIF using the old Stack Overflow icon only.
Can this be updated with the recent Stack Overflow icon?

Screenshot for reference:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out - you've got sharp eyes! I saw the GIF this morning on Twitter and didn't notice.

We won't be fixing this specific image but we've made sure that the people creating these images have up-to-date versions of our logos and other digital assets, so hopefully we won't see this again. It's pretty amazing how the old logo likes to pop in from time to time.